# Setting 'document' in FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox

Newer versions of FireFox will not allow javascript to modify the 'document' variable. All of the following will result in a "Permission denied to access property 'document'" error:

```
document=top.document;
document=parent.document;
document=window.parent.document;
document=window.top.document;
```

I find myself searching for a solution to set the 'document' variable across browsers. FireFox is currently the only browser that will not allow this. Is there any javascript solution for this problem?

It is being used, in this case, as a method of displaying AdSense ads in an iframe. Google grants special permission to some companies to be able to do this. Here is a link with some example code:

http://geoland.org/2007/01/adsense-in-iframe/

The document replacement is used in the iframe so that ads are sent with the parent referrer. This is important for AdSense, otherwise all revenue is deemed invalid for non-matching referrers. Perhaps there is another method of using the parent's referrer in the child iframe? Assuming the child iframe is cross-domain.

Comment: Why do you want to overwrite the document object?

Comment: This sounds a little bit like a design problem

Comment: Or an "I don't know how this works so I'm going to do something weird" problem.

Comment: It's a method of setting AdSense ads in an iframe. It requires setting the iframe's document as the parent document so that the referrer matches. Before you jump all over me, yes, Google frowns upon the placement of AdSense ads in an iframe. They also grant permission in special cases.

Comment: Also: http://geoland.org/2007/01/adsense-in-iframe/ for an example of integrating AdSense within an IFRAME.

Comment: Ah, I'd recommend updating your question to include this new information a bit more prominently.

Comment: If you look at the Adsense program policies. It forbids iframes. http://www.seroundtable.com/google-adsense-iframe-13486.html

Comment: "It is being used, in this case, as a method of displaying AdSense ads in an iframe. Google grants special permission to some companies to be able to do this."

At least read the question...

Answer (score 0):

The Firefox behavior is what the spec requires.  See the `[Unforgeable]` annotation on `document` at http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/browsers.html#the-window-object and the definition of `[Unforgeable]` at http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/WebIDL/#Unforgeable

That said, how is adsense determining the "referrer"?  Can you just modify the relevant properties on the document object in the iframe?